# PHP date() function returning incorrect values

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

I have a timestamp of "1377592503467" stored in a variable and when I pass it to php's date() function, it returns a value of "1935-05-26 03:04:11".  Hopefully I am missing something obvious; below is my code.  The timestamp represents 2013-08-27 15:57:45 but that's not what is being returned.

```
$date = "1377592503467";
$formattedDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $date);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like that timestamp is in *milliseconds*, not seconds as PHP uses them.

Do `date(..., $date / 1000)`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's exactly in milliseconds, since (GMT+04): `2013-08-27 08:35:03` is a corresponding date for `1377592503`

Comment: @Alma True, but at least it gets you into the right ballpark. I'm not aware of a generally applicable timestamp format which in addition has a few hours of skew, so I'd just err on the side of the OP providing incorrect information. :)

Comment: I wanted to ask in comment why OP providing timestamp larger than `2^31-1` (i.e. max for signed longint) - but since there's high rated answer, it seems, you're correct.

Comment: I don't know how the OP got that timestamp, but the microsecond explanation makes more sense. See [this](http://codepad.org/5DXskuvG).

Comment: Thanks deceze!  Appreciate the help from all.  I used the /1000 as a solution.